# Python based games - how are they made?

Tags: c++, python

According to this list ---> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Python_software#Video_games there are several games written in python but it looks like some of them are commercial, so the source code can't be shown to the users and the game should run even on a computer where there's no python installation. So my question is: How are they made? Are they combined with a C++ code or built in a C++ program?

Comment: This really is multiple questions in one. Which part are you interested in: How to write a game in Python, how to distribute a game written in Python without depending on a pre-existing Python installation, how do distribute a game written in Python without giving away your source code, how to combine Python and C++, or something different? Each of those is a reasonable question, but just "how are games made" is not.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people use PyGame or build their own libraries on top of PyGame. Theoretically, yes some of them do interface with C++. For instance, Mount and Blade's modding system (affectionately known as modules) are entirely programmed in Python using hooks to the main engine.

I've not seen a huge amount of games developed on Python however and this is likely due to the lack of amazing GUI packages. There are some decent 2 and 3D graphical packages in existence, but compared with languages like Java, C#, C++, etc. they're still very limited.

The biggest thing to note, is that Python is supplemental to many of the games listed in the page you linked to it, it is not the main engine.

Comment: Good GUI libraries in Java?! WHERE?!

Comment: @JustinDanielson JOGL (Java OpenGL) is decently powerful and has a few fledgling game engines written in to it.

Comment: @DylanLawrence: And you think PyGame and Panda3D and the like are limited compared to JOGL and those fledgling game engines? Both languages are behind C++ for 3D graphics engines, but the idea that Python is further behind than Java is a stretch…

Comment: @abarnert Minecraft was built in Java. I've never seen a large scale built in Python. Are those specifically examples good arguments for one or the other? Probably not.

Comment: @DylanLawrence: Minecraft (intentionally) isn't exactly an example of a powerful, complex modern GUI… There are plenty of games written in both languages that do a lot more than it does. Look at all the Disney VR stuff (downloadable games, live attractions at the amusement parks, etc.) using what became Panda3D in Python.

Comment: I love Mount and Blade! I wish people made more games like that, combining sim/strategy with other elements like action and RPG elements... like Pirates!, X-Com, M&B... say, do you guys know any others like this? I'm hungry for more games like this. Also it's cool to hear that M&B is modded with Python.

Answer (score 2):

Let's get this out of the way first:

> the game should run even on a computer where there's no python installation. So my question is: How are they made

Normally, games built (wholly or partly) in Python do not rely on the user's Python installation, but instead bundle up their own. Even for pure-Python games, this is pretty easy to do with tools like `pyInstaller`, `py2app`, `py2exe`, `cx_Freeze`, etc.

---

And:

> the source code can't be shown to the users

Shipping compiled code instead of source code provides almost no protection against piracy, cheaters, competitors stealing your ideas, etc. This is simply not a concern for any commercial game.

And some of these—like Civilization IV—explicitly *wanted* the users to see (some of) the source code, to serve as sample code and/or API documentation for modders.

---

Finally:

> Are they combined with a C++ code or built in a C++ program?

Well, for one thing, not every native program is built in C++. OS X and iOS expect complex GUI stuff to be done in Objective C. Gtk+ expects it to be done in C (or Vala, or…). Android requires Java. Only Windows really demands C++.

But beyond that, there is no one answer to your question. There are multiple ways to use Python in games, and almost all of those ways are used by different games in the list. For example:

In an online game like Eve Online, the *server* can be written in pure Python (or Python apps behind a web server written in some other language), even if the clients are written in a completely different language. (In the case of a web game, the clients are obviously written in JavaScript+HTML+CSS, or ActionScript/Flash.) The hard part of the game logic is mostly on the server, and that's the part you want to make easy to write.

Even in a local game, you can split the game into an interface and an engine. Again, this means the hard part of the game logic is in the engine, which you can write in Python to make it easy to write, while the part that has to be lightning-responsive and use platform-specific functionality can be in C++ or ObjC or whatever is appropriate for the platform.

Even within an engine, you can combine C (or C++, or even Java or .NET) and Python code by building custom C extensions for the Python code to use, or by embedding the Python interpreter in a C app, or both.

Of course you *can* write the interface itself in Python too, most commonly by using PyGame.

You could even turn everything around backward if you really wanted to—write a PyGame interface with an engine implemented in C that talked to a server written in JavaScript. That's not as common as the opposite, but there's nothing stopping you from doing it.

So, Eve Online has a pure Python server. Civilization IV has a Python interpreter embedded in its engine. Frets on Fire is all Python, with PyGame. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Most of those programs are primarily written in C or C++ and then a Python interpreter is [embedded](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/index.html) into them. The native code provides modules and objects that the Python code can examine and manipulate in order to affect the native structures.

Comment: That's true of _some_ of the games, but nowhere near all of them. In fact, if you read the list, it pretty clearly tells you that.